# Convex Optimization - Currency exchange problem - cvxpy error

Tags: python, cvxpy, convex-optimization

I am solving the currency exchange problem, where we have a set of currency holdings for 10 different kinds. Our objective is to have a specific minimum of each currency holdings, while minimizing the loss due to the bid-ask spread which occurs when we exchange some units of a currency for some units of another currency.

In case it helps here is the full question:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1DG8xfM3ayQ0Oj9VQGYSNbHF_rbKHMTLq/view

The code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cvxpy as cp

# Exchange rate data. Obtained from website
tickers = ["USD", "EUR", "GBP", "CAD", "JPY", "CNY", "RUB", "MXN", "INR", "BRL"]
n = len(tickers)
F = np.zeros((n, n))
# USD
data = ([1.0, 0.87, 0.76, 1.31, 108.90, 6.72, 65.45, 19.11, 71.13, 3.69],
# EUR
[1.0, 0.88, 1.51, 125.15, 7.72, 75.23, 21.96, 81.85, 4.24],
# GBP
[1.0, 1.72, 142.94, 8.82, 85.90, 25.08, 93.50, 4.84],
# CAD
[1.0, 82.93, 5.11, 49.82, 14.54, 54.23, 2.81],
# JPY
[1.0, 0.062, 0.60, 0.18, 0.65, 0.034],
# CNY
[1.0, 9.74, 2.85, 10.61, 0.55],
# RUB
[1.0, 0.29, 1.09, 0.056],
# MXN
[1.0, 3.73, 0.19],
# INR
[1.0, 0.052],
# BRL
[1.0])
for i in range(n):
    F[i,i:] = data[i]
for j in range(n):
    for i in range(j+1,n):
        F[i,j] = 1.035/F[j,i]
        
# Initial and final portfolios.
c_req = np.arange(1,n+1)
c_req = 1e4*c_req/c_req.sum()
c_init = c_req[::-1]

X = cp.Variable((n,n))
c_final = c_init - cp.matmul(cp.transpose(X/F),np.ones(n)) + cp.matmul(X/F,np.ones(n)) # final number of currency holdings 
value_per_currency = np.zeros(n) # value per currency unit in USD
for i in range(n):
    value_per_currency[i] = pow(F[i][0]/F[0][i] , 0.5) # value per currency unit in USD


Loss = cp.matmul((c_init - c_final),value_per_currency) # Loss in currency valued as the GM of bid and ask price in USD
        

        
# Defining the convex optimization problem 
objective = cp.Minimize(Loss) # Loss is minimised
constraints =  [X>=0, cp.diag(X)==0] # constraints added
constraints += [cp.matmul(cp.transpose(X),np.ones(n))<=c_init]
for i in range(n):
        constraints += [c_final[i] >= c_req[i]]
        
prob = cp.Problem(objective, constraints) # Problem defined

result = prob.solve() # solution
initial_value = np.dot(value_per_currency, c_init)
final_value = np.dot(value_per_currency, c_final)

print("The initial currency holdings is:\n\n", c_init);print("\n")
print("The final currency holdings is:\n\n", c_final);print("\n")
print("The initial value of holdings = ", initial_value, "USD")
print("The final value of holdings = \n", final_value, "USD")
```

The output:

```
The initial currency holdings is:

 [1818.18181818 1636.36363636 1454.54545455 1272.72727273 1090.90909091
  909.09090909  727.27272727  545.45454545  363.63636364  181.81818182]


The final currency holdings is:

 [1818.18181818 1636.36363636 1454.54545455 1272.72727273 1090.90909091
  909.09090909  727.27272727  545.45454545  363.63636364  181.81818182] + -var562 / [[1.00000000e+00 8.70000000e-01 7.60000000e-01 1.31000000e+00
  1.08900000e+02 6.72000000e+00 6.54500000e+01 1.91100000e+01
  7.11300000e+01 3.69000000e+00]
 [1.18965517e+00 1.00000000e+00 8.80000000e-01 1.51000000e+00
  1.25150000e+02 7.72000000e+00 7.52300000e+01 2.19600000e+01
  8.18500000e+01 4.24000000e+00]
 [1.36184211e+00 1.17613636e+00 1.00000000e+00 1.72000000e+00
  1.42940000e+02 8.82000000e+00 8.59000000e+01 2.50800000e+01
  9.35000000e+01 4.84000000e+00]
 [7.90076336e-01 6.85430464e-01 6.01744186e-01 1.00000000e+00
  8.29300000e+01 5.11000000e+00 4.98200000e+01 1.45400000e+01
  5.42300000e+01 2.81000000e+00]
 [9.50413223e-03 8.27007591e-03 7.24080034e-03 1.24804052e-02
  1.00000000e+00 6.20000000e-02 6.00000000e-01 1.80000000e-01
  6.50000000e-01 3.40000000e-02]
 [1.54017857e-01 1.34067358e-01 1.17346939e-01 2.02544031e-01
  1.66935484e+01 1.00000000e+00 9.74000000e+00 2.85000000e+00
  1.06100000e+01 5.50000000e-01]
 [1.58135982e-02 1.37578094e-02 1.20488941e-02 2.07747892e-02
  1.72500000e+00 1.06262834e-01 1.00000000e+00 2.90000000e-01
  1.09000000e+00 5.60000000e-02]
 [5.41601256e-02 4.71311475e-02 4.12679426e-02 7.11829436e-02
  5.75000000e+00 3.63157895e-01 3.56896552e+00 1.00000000e+00
  3.73000000e+00 1.90000000e-01]
 [1.45508224e-02 1.26450825e-02 1.10695187e-02 1.90853771e-02
  1.59230769e+00 9.75494816e-02 9.49541284e-01 2.77479893e-01
  1.00000000e+00 5.20000000e-02]
 [2.80487805e-01 2.44103774e-01 2.13842975e-01 3.68327402e-01
  3.04411765e+01 1.88181818e+00 1.84821429e+01 5.44736842e+00
  1.99038462e+01 1.00000000e+00]].T @ [1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1.] + (var562 / [[1.00000000e+00 8.70000000e-01 7.60000000e-01 1.31000000e+00
  1.08900000e+02 6.72000000e+00 6.54500000e+01 1.91100000e+01
  7.11300000e+01 3.69000000e+00]
 [1.18965517e+00 1.00000000e+00 8.80000000e-01 1.51000000e+00
  1.25150000e+02 7.72000000e+00 7.52300000e+01 2.19600000e+01
  8.18500000e+01 4.24000000e+00]
 [1.36184211e+00 1.17613636e+00 1.00000000e+00 1.72000000e+00
  1.42940000e+02 8.82000000e+00 8.59000000e+01 2.50800000e+01
  9.35000000e+01 4.84000000e+00]
 [7.90076336e-01 6.85430464e-01 6.01744186e-01 1.00000000e+00
  8.29300000e+01 5.11000000e+00 4.98200000e+01 1.45400000e+01
  5.42300000e+01 2.81000000e+00]
 [9.50413223e-03 8.27007591e-03 7.24080034e-03 1.24804052e-02
  1.00000000e+00 6.20000000e-02 6.00000000e-01 1.80000000e-01
  6.50000000e-01 3.40000000e-02]
 [1.54017857e-01 1.34067358e-01 1.17346939e-01 2.02544031e-01
  1.66935484e+01 1.00000000e+00 9.74000000e+00 2.85000000e+00
  1.06100000e+01 5.50000000e-01]
 [1.58135982e-02 1.37578094e-02 1.20488941e-02 2.07747892e-02
  1.72500000e+00 1.06262834e-01 1.00000000e+00 2.90000000e-01
  1.09000000e+00 5.60000000e-02]
 [5.41601256e-02 4.71311475e-02 4.12679426e-02 7.11829436e-02
  5.75000000e+00 3.63157895e-01 3.56896552e+00 1.00000000e+00
  3.73000000e+00 1.90000000e-01]
 [1.45508224e-02 1.26450825e-02 1.10695187e-02 1.90853771e-02
  1.59230769e+00 9.75494816e-02 9.49541284e-01 2.77479893e-01
  1.00000000e+00 5.20000000e-02]
 [2.80487805e-01 2.44103774e-01 2.13842975e-01 3.68327402e-01
  3.04411765e+01 1.88181818e+00 1.84821429e+01 5.44736842e+00
  1.99038462e+01 1.00000000e+00]]) @ [1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1.]


The initial value of holdings =  6910.667218038612 USD
The final value of holdings = 
 [Expression(AFFINE, UNKNOWN, (10,)) Expression(AFFINE, UNKNOWN, (10,))
 Expression(AFFINE, UNKNOWN, (10,)) Expression(AFFINE, UNKNOWN, (10,))
 Expression(AFFINE, UNKNOWN, (10,)) Expression(AFFINE, UNKNOWN, (10,))
 Expression(AFFINE, UNKNOWN, (10,)) Expression(AFFINE, UNKNOWN, (10,))
 Expression(AFFINE, UNKNOWN, (10,)) Expression(AFFINE, UNKNOWN, (10,))] USD
```

Looking at c_final, I realise that the "var562" is left unsolved, hence we cannot resolve it completely (right?)

How can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wherever you are operating on cvxpy objects you should be using `cp.` functions, not `np.` ones. So `cp.dot` etc.

Comment: Yes, I saw that later and changed some things. Now there seems to be another issue that I am not able to resolve yet.

Comment: You have to use ``c_final.value``. See the first example on https://www.cvxpy.org/index.html